# nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even) selectors behavior by different class

Tags: html, css

I have elements with different background colors separated by `nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` selectors

```
<!-- <div class="s">s</div> -->
<div class="r">r</div>
<div class="r">r</div>
<div class="r">r</div>
<div class="r">r</div>
<div class="r">r</div>
```

CSS:

```
.s {
  background: #FFF;
}
.r:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #e3e5e5;
}
.r:nth-child(even) {
    background: #FFF;
}
```

As expected, first element have gray background.

Then uncomment first HTML line, which has different `.s` class, this changes `.r` class elements behavior, because first `.r` class element now have white background.

https://jsfiddle.net/pu5yzgf7/1/

Why? What I'm missing?

Comment: Pseudo-elements match elements, not classes of elements. Adding a class to the selector makes it act like a filter.

Comment: nth-child doesn't work based on class, you might have to work with nth-of-type

Comment: @karthick it's the same for nth-of-type